# Optimistic response not working when adding items to list

Tags: graphql, apollo

My data model is a list with items. Very simple:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: "List 1",
  items: [
    { _id: 2, text: "Item text 1" },
    { _id: 3, text: "Item text 2" }
   ]
}
```

Adding a new list with optimistic response works perfectly:

```
  const [addListMutation] = useAddListMutation({
    update: (cache, { data }) => {
      const cachedLists =
        (cache.readQuery<GetAllListsQuery>({
          query: GetAllListsDocument,
        })?.lists as TList[]) ?? [];

      if (data) {
        cache.writeQuery({
          query: GetAllListsDocument,
          data: {
            lists: [...cachedLists, data?.list as TList],
          },
        });
      }
    },
  });
  
  const addList = async (name: string) => {
    const list = {
      _id: ..new id here,
      name,
      items: [],
    };

    const variables: AddListMutationVariables = {
      data: list,
    };

    await addListMutation({
      variables,
      optimisticResponse: {
        list,
      },
    });
  };
```

This gets reflected immediately in my component using `const { loading, data } = useGetAllListsQuery();`. data is updated twice; first with the optimistic response and then after the mutation is done. Just like expected.

Now I'm trying to add an **item** to the list this way:

```
  const [updateListMutation] = useUpdateListMutation({
    update: (cache, { data }) => {
      const cachedLists =
        (cache.readQuery<GetAllListsQuery>(
          {
            query: GetAllListsDocument,
          },
        )?.lists as TList[]) ?? [];

      if (data?.list) {
        // Find existing list to update
        const updatedList = data?.list as TList;
        const updatedListIndex = cachedLists.findIndex(
          (list: TList) => list._id === updatedList._id,
        );
      
        // Create a copy of cached lists and replace entire list
        // with new list from { data }.
        const updatedLists = [...cachedLists];
        updatedLists[updatedListIndex] = { ...updatedList };

        cache.writeQuery({
          query: GetAllListsDocument,
          data: {
           lists: updatedLists,
          },
        });
      }
    }
  });

  const updateList = async (updatedList: TList) => {
    const variables: UpdateListMutationVariables = {
      query: {
        _id: updatedList._id,
      },
      set: updatedList,
    };

    await updateListMutation({
      variables,
      optimisticResponse: {
        list: updatedList,
      },
    });
  };

  const addListItem = async (list: TList, text: string) => {
    const updatedList = R.clone(list);

    updatedList.items.push({
      _id: ...new item id here,
      text: 'My new list item',
    });

    await updateList(updatedList);
  };
```

**The problem is** is in my component and the `const { loading, data } = useGetAllListsQuery();` not returning what I expect. When data first changes with the optimistic response it contains an empty list item:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: "List 1",
  items: [{}]
}
```

And only after the mutation response returns, it populates the items array with the item with text 'My new list item'. So my component first updates when the mutation is finished and not with the optimistic response because it can't figure out to update the array. Don't know why?
(and I *have* checked that the updatedLists array in writeQuery correctly contains the new item with text 'My new list item' so I'm trying to write the correct data).

Please let me know if you have any hints or solutions.

I've tried playing around with the cache (right now it's just initialized default like new InMemoryCache({})). I can see the cache is normalized with a bunch of List:1, List:2, ... and ListItem:3, ListItem:4, ...
Tried to disable normalization so I only have List:{id} entries. Didn't help. Also tried to add __typename: 'ListItem' to item added, but that only caused the { data } in the update: ... for the optimistic response to be undefined. I have used hours on this now. It should be a fairly simple and common use case what I'm trying to do :).

package.json

```
"@apollo/client": "^3.3.4",
"graphql": "^15.4.0",
"@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^1.19.0",
```

Comment: shape of mutation/response? ... `data` doesn't contain `list`?

Comment: data does contain list and the item in the items array in both optimistic and mutation result, but after the optimistic response the data returned in my useGetAllListsQuery() query does have the list but not the item in the items array (empty {}). But a few hundred ms later when mutation is finished, the item is not empty anymore...
I guess it must be something about the cache I don't know about when writing optimistic responses in nested arrays maybe...it works in first level of the object.

Comment: show network response

Comment: {"data":{"list":{"__typename":"List","_id":"603b5bce7416d89b890b0146","items":[{"__typename":"ListItem","_id":"603bc42a1e6ca01cb4e55c3c","text":"My list item"}],"name":"My list"}}}

Comment: hmmm, I would add `__typename: 'ListItem'` items.push object

Comment: I end up getting an empty array [] in my component with useGetAllListsQuery() when I add __typename: 'ListItem' when doing the items.push. Only when the mutation is done the array is populated correctly. No idea why...